# post to friends wall facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have problem about  post something  to friends wall..i actually want to do that without popup dialog appear ..like frictionless request ..i use following script but i realize that nothing happen with this script ..i need some instruction to do that..i don't want dialog box to appear and i have granted permission" publish_stream"  for that .but i'm failed ..need your help

```
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function post_friend_wall()
  {
alert("try"); 
var user_id = document.getElementById("friendid").value;
var data = {
    name: "title of post",
    caption: "caption of post",
    description: "description of post"
};
var callback = function (response) {};
FB.api("/" + user_id + "/feed", "post", data, callback);
  if (!response || response.error) {
        // an error occured
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
      } else {
        // Done
        alert('did');
      }
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: It is not possible any more to post to other people’s walls via API.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback will not work.  Since the request is asynchron, you cannot just access some of the values from callback.

```
var callback = function (response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        // an error occured
        alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
      } else {
        // Done
        alert('did');
      }
};
FB.api("/" + user_id + "/feed", "post", data, callback);
```